I want to send message to dead letter queue of azure service bus upon message validation fails
upon validation failed like any message field is empty or null directly send to dead letter queue of Azure service bus at first instance (without its maximum Retry.) I tried SurviceBusSenderClient and ServiceBusSenderAsynch and send method but its retry for max time that set at azure bus. but i want it should go in first instance only when validations fails.

`This is my Config class to listen messages from service bus
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ServiceBusListenConnectionDetails.class})
@ConditionalOnExpression(
"${messaging.enabled:true}"
)
public class AzureServiceBusInboundMessagesListenerConfiguration  {
@Bean
public ServiceBusInboundChannelAdapter inboundMessagesServiceBusInboundChannelAdapter(ServiceBusListenConnectionDetails listenConnectionDetails) {
ServiceBusInboundChannelAdapter adapter = serviceBusInboundChannelAdapter(listenConnectionDetails.getInboundMessages());
System.out.print(adapter);
return adapter;
}
@Override
@Bean(name = InputChannelConst.INBOUND_MESSAGES_QUEUE_CHANNEL)
protected MessageChannel inputChannel() {
    return input();
}

}
In service class i get message and check for validation as below
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = InputChannelConst.INBOUND_MESSAGES_QUEUE_CHANNEL) public void beforeSenttoSegment(byte[] payload, @Header(AzureHeaders.CHECKPOINTER) Checkpointer checkPointer)
throws IOException {
objectMapper.enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES);
InboundMessage<String> inboundMessageEventPayload = objectMapper.readValue(payload,
new TypeReference<InboundMessage<String>>() {
            }); 

try {payloadvalidator.payloadValidator(property);
segmentService.sendInboundMessageEventToSegment(inboundMessageEventPayload, property);
checkPointer.success().doOnSuccess(s -> LOGGER.info("Inbound Message: '{}' successfully check-pointed", inboundMessageEventPayload))
.doOnError(e -> LOGGER.error("Error found when check-pointed Inbound Message", e)).block();
    } catch (CustomValidationException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to process the Inbound message", e.getValidationErrors());
        checkPointer.failure().block();
        throw e;
    }

this is my validator class
@Component
public class PayloadValidator {your text
private final Validator validator;
public <T> void payloadValidator(T payload) {
Set\<ConstraintViolation\<T\>\> violations = validator.validate(payload);   if (!violations.isEmpty()) {        Map\<String, String\> validationErrors = new HashMap\<\>();         for (ConstraintViolation\<T\> violation : violations) {             validationErrors.put(violation.getPropertyPath().toString(), violation.getMessage());       }       throw new CustomValidationException("Payload validation failed", validationErrors);

    }

}


Messages can be dewd-lettered manually using client SDK. Or messages will be automatically dead-lettered after all delivery attempts have failed. You cannot "send" a message directly to. a dead-letter queue.

Sean is correct that there isn't a direct way to "send" a message to a dead-letter queue (DLQ) using the Azure Service Bus SDK. Instead, you mark the message as dead-lettered, and the Service Bus handles moving it to the DLQ. You can manually dead-letter a message if validation fails, without waiting for the maximum retry attempts.
